# How can I load translation files from the data directory once they have been stored there?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngx-translate

I am creating an app using the [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/) and I am trying to make as much of the app available to work offline when there is no internet connection available.

So upon first load of the app, I would like it to download the translations from a server and then store them within the data directory. Then upon subsequent loads, the app will check with the server to see if there is a new translation file available and download as necessary.

Once saved within the data directory, I would like to configure ngx-translate to read from those JSON files in the data directory when a getTranslation is called.

So far, I have managed to create a custom loader and configured ngx-translate to use this custom loader. I have also managed to fetch the translation files from one location and save them in another. For now, rather than pulling them from the server, I am moving them from the app www directory to the data directory as I haven't got the server environment set up so trying to 'mock' functionality as much as possible in the meantime.

```
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
  const subDirectory = 'i18n';
  const fileName = lang;
  const fileExtension = '.json';
  let rootDirectory = '';
  let rootDirectoryPath = '';
  let directory = '';
  let directoryPath = '';
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    this.platform.ready()
      .then(() => {
        rootDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;
        rootDirectoryPath = rootDirectory;
        directory = rootDirectoryPath + subDirectory;
        directoryPath = directory + '/';
        console.log(directoryPath + fileName + fileExtension + ':');
        const translationFilePath = this.webview.convertFileSrc(directoryPath + fileName + fileExtension);
        // return this.http.get(translationFilePath);
        return this.http.get(translationFilePath)
          .pipe(map((res: JSON) => {
            return res;
          }));
      });
  } else {
    rootDirectory = '/assets/data';
    rootDirectoryPath = rootDirectory + '/';
    directory = rootDirectoryPath + subDirectory;
    directoryPath = directory + '/';
    console.log(directoryPath + fileName + fileExtension + ':');
    return this.http.get(directoryPath + fileName + fileExtension);
  }
}
```

When I am running in the browser (and cordova is not available), this function works and returns the translation files from /assets/data to be able to translate.

However, when cordova is available within the app, I get an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at t.getTranslation (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at t.retrieveTranslations (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at t.use (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1
    at new t (polyfills.30cd1d148106f6301a8e.js:1)
    at t.changeLanguage (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at n.selectLanguage (19.8a90e2507f2b3a13dd11.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (19.8a90e2507f2b3a13dd11.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.30cd1d148106f6301a8e.js:1)
    at new t (polyfills.30cd1d148106f6301a8e.js:1)
    at t.changeLanguage (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at n.selectLanguage (19.8a90e2507f2b3a13dd11.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (19.8a90e2507f2b3a13dd11.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at Object.handleEvent (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at na (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
    at main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (main.db14319ec6098ffa1c27.js:1)
```

Any advice and support with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a different approach.. don't load it from file, load it from a class.

Use a library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core

Edit:
Ok i guess your error occur because ionic changes the relative path and the way you set src="" for images etc..

I'd try first to load an image from that same directory and see if it works.. try reading about assets serving in ionic app

Comment: I am not sure you have understood this fully. I am using **ngx-translate/core**. I am just trying to implement a custom loader. Something like [here](https://medium.com/@nsrathore/custom-loader-for-ngx-translate-core-7d87b00904d) but reading from the data directory instead.

Comment: I see, let me ask one basic question, do you try to load a file with angular?
because this is impossible. angular is running on the browser and not on the system level therefore it cant load files 

Nodejs can do it trough fs

What you could do is create a webservice that will return these files data.

Comment: I am happy to change how I load the file (if given some an example of how to achieve this) but I am not sure that's the issue here. I am fairly sure its reading the file okay but maybe its not returning the **Observable** in a way that can be understood by **ngx-translate**.

Comment: In the end I wrote my own translations service.